# text can't be left aligned

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want my whole section to be left aligned. This is my #CSS code:

```css
#Gender{text-align:left;}
```

```html
<label id="Gender">
Your Gender: <br>
<label for="male">
    <input id="male" type="radio" name="male-female">male
</label><br>
<label for="female">
    <input id="female" type="radio" name="male-female">female
</label><br>
```

Answer (score 3):

text-align only works for block elements.

Use an appropriate block element or add display block

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#Gender{
   display:block / inline-block;
   text-align:left;
}
```